# How can I separate JSON object elements into separate arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, parsing

```
{'labels': 'Middle East', 'default': 193}
{'labels': 'Coronavirus pandemic', 'default': 116}
{'labels': 'Europe', 'default': 90}
{'labels': 'United States', 'default': 67}
{'labels': 'Health', 'default': 63}
```

I have JSON objects like above.

I am trying to make below type array in python. plz help

```
{'labels': ['Middle East', 'Coronavirus pandemic', 'Europe', 'United States', 'Health'], 'default': [193, 116, 90, 67, 63]}
```

Comment: Is the json shown above an array ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, assuming you have all those dictionaries inside an array:

```
dictionaries=[
{'labels': 'Middle East', 'default': 193},
{'labels': 'Coronavirus pandemic', 'default': 116},
{'labels': 'Europe', 'default': 90},
{'labels': 'United States', 'default': 67},
{'labels': 'Health', 'default': 63}]

labels=[d['labels'] for d in dictionaries]
default=[d['default'] for d in dictionaries]
result={'labels' : labels, 'default': default}
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'labels': ['Middle East', 'Coronavirus pandemic', 'Europe', 'United States', 'Health'], 'default': [193, 116, 90, 67, 63]}
```

Comment: but i do not have dictionary available for applying loop

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function `merge` that can take multiple dictionaries and then merge those dictionaries

```
def merge(*dicts):
    res = {}
    for d in dicts:
        for key in d.keys():
            if key in res:
                res[key].append(d[key])
            else:
                res[key] = []
                res[key].append(d[key])
    return res

a = {'labels': 'Middle East', 'default': 193}
b = {'labels': 'Coronavirus pandemic', 'default': 116}
c = {'labels': 'Europe', 'default': 90}
d = {'labels': 'United States', 'default': 67}
e = {'labels': 'Health', 'default': 63}
c = merge(a, b, c, d, e)
print(c)
```

output:

```
{'labels': ['Middle East', 'Coronavirus pandemic', 'Europe', 'United States', 'Health'], 'default': [193, 116, 90, 67, 63]}
```